# Upper right corner (home)

Tags: visual, pattern, letter-sequence

### What letter should replace the "?". Explain why.

---

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The missing letter is:

> **M**

Because what's represented here is:

> the 'upper right corner' of [the 'home' screen of this website](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/):
>
>  [image: Screenshot of the PSE homepage]
>
>  The letters are the initials of the words which appear on the key buttons shown on-screen. 'A Q' is 'Ask Question', 'A' is 'Active', 'H' is 'Hot' and 'W' is 'Week'. What's missing is the '**M**' for '**Month**'.

Comment: I had a feeling this would either take a while or it would be solved very fast. Well done!